How to handle the read latency in Async FIFO?
I am using Xilinx FIFO generator core in my project. I have module, say M1, which assersts fifo_rd_en signal to the fifo that i am using. However, the fifo has a read latency of 2 clock cycles. How should i handle this latency, so that the data out of fifo after the read_en is deasserted will not be lost. Note: my module, M1 will not accept data after it deasserts the fifo_rd_en signal. If possible please explain different methods to broaden my view.

If you post code for the fifo, the M1 module, and the testbench as a minimal-reproducible-example , then we can respond with code. If you post a hypothetical behavioral description question, you will get hypothetical behavioral description answers.

Are you using Vivado or ISE?

A couple of ideas:

Insert some logic (could be a module) between the fifo and your M1 module to capture the data and behave like a buffer.  This problem comes up in AXI streaming protocols and the solution is sometimes called a 'skid buffer'. Internet search 'fpga skid buffer' to see what others have written on the topic.  I get several hits which are all informative.  This is my favorite Zip CPU Skid Buffer
Create a 1-clk delayed version of fifo_rd_en and use it as a valid to capture data coming from the fifo into a vector of flip-flops (call it 'data_capture'). After the first burst of reads data_capture should have the
last value which you were previously loosing. Use mux to select the data driven to the M1 module as data_capture or the data directly from the fifo.  On the first clk cycle of a read burst use the mux to select data_capture, after that use the mux to select data coming from the fifo.  Use a small state machine to keep track of the beginning of the read burst.  The read burst can be one in length.  Use mealy inputs/outputs to/from the state machine to control the mux select.  Set the state machine output reset-default to be data from the fifo.



IP catalog offers the choice of latency, when the core is generated.  Choose the latency that meets the needs of the surrounding logic.


This does address my concern, thank you. I will try it.
